# css .class doesn't work on anchor tag unless i add a.class. why?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have a simple css class that i use to style buttons and anchor tags, but there is something strange.

```
.green
 {
    background-color: #35db22;
    color:white;
 }
```

When i apply it to a button, it works fine. but when i try to apply it to a anchor tag, it doesn't, while other classes like my 'button' class do work on the anchor tag.

```
<a class="button green">green</a>
```

While i was debugging this, i found out it does work by adding `a.green` to the class selectors:

```
.green, a.green
{
   background-color: #35db22;
   color:white;
}
```

Am i the only one that thinks this is strange? Why is this happening?
I have a lot more of these classes so adding it to all of them takes a lot of time... :(

Any idea what's going on? or is this just a bug in css?

**EDIT**

Here's some more css because ZachSaucier asked for it:

```
/*CONTROLS*/
button, a.button, input[type="submit"], input[type="button"] 
{

    text-align:center;

    min-height:20px;
    min-width:100px;
    font-size:20px;

    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;

    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
button:hover, a.button:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover
{
    background-color:gray;
    color:whitesmoke;
}

button:active, a.button:active, input[type="submit"]:active, input[type="button"]:active
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}


.green
{
    background-color: #35db22;
    color:white;
}
```

i'm a css beginner, so this might be something obvious...

Comment: It's likely due to selector specificity. Another rule is probably overriding the original. We'll have to see all of your CSS or a demo to confirm this.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you define `.button` later in your CSS, perhaps?

Comment: @ZachSaucier all of the css? that's a lot but okay.

Comment: @DavidThomas no, .button is one of the things that are defined first and .green is somewhere at the bottom.

Comment: @JoJo `a.button` is the one overriding it based on my first glance. It is indeed a specificity issue. Using dev tools to catch things like this is best way. [This page](http://specificity.keegan.st/) can help you understand how CSS selectors are weighed in regards to specificity

Comment: @ZachSaucier i didn't know there where tools to debug css, what tools do you mean. And thanks!

Comment: @JoJo As Artur said, press f12 or right click something and click "Inspect Element" or something similar depending on your browser. You can then look at the styles applied to each element and which rules are overriding which

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks, i see it's in IE. i'll switch to IE for debugging then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is either there is a `.button` rule somewhere after `.green` definition, which overrides the `.green` rule.

Or there is a `a.button` rule which is just more specific than `.green` which overrides the `.green` class.

By changing the `.green` class `a.green` you are making the selector more specific and the `a.green` selector is now for the browser more important.

You can check the developer tools of whatever browser you are using and check to see what overrides the values in `.green` class. You can usually open the developer tools by pressing F12 and I'm sure you can find information about developer tools and how to use it on the web.